# universal text data format converter

Tags: conversion, csv

I'm looking for a bidirectional file serialization format converter: xml, json, csv, sql table, excel, html, etc.

I've only found tools that performs unidirectional conversion from one format to another:

- csv2any https://github.com/shancarter/Mr-Data-Converter
- any2csv https://github.com/onyxfish/csvkit/blob/master/csvkit/utilities/in2csv.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand your question. I think you want to be able to convert from any text format to csv or vice-versa. If that's correct. You may want to take a look at ParseNIP   - that may help you.

Comment: i'm interested in [binary serialization formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats) too.